# rails set custom HTTP response?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, http-headers

Im trying to return a custom HTTP response, based on condition I want to return true or false, the right response is calculated in my /api/validate function

Have tried nummerous things all fail. How to just return true or false?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your can not return just true or false.
You have to return correct http response with status code. For example

- `200 OK` – true
- `422 Unprocessable Entity` – false

Or you can always return 200 OK with hash object converted to JSON in body of your response. Something like

```
{ :result => true }.to_json
```

Comment: somewhat in right direction :render => true was the way to go thx